# Using multiple sheets within a google Chart API (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, sql, google-visualization

Within my code for a Google Chart, I use a SELECT function to query the associated Google sheet for the Rows and Columns I will be using

I believe the query I am using is SQL, so with that fact in mind, I use the following Query to attempt to select Data from another sheet:

```
SELECT A, B, C, D
FROM 'Sheet 2'
```

However an error comes up saying that the syntax is incorrect. Below is the code for the chart itself, which, when there is no FROM syntax placed into the code, displays perfectly:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
    google.load("visualization", '1', {packages:['corechart', 'bar']});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
          var query = new google.visualization.Query(
              'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oKxlfCjcvjCzGh8fpTX3ax7qWbWA2uVVQgk-jzOWX3k/edit?usp=sharing');
            query.setQuery('SELECT A, B, C, D FROM "Sheet 2"');
          query.send(handleQueryResponse);
        }

        function handleQueryResponse(response) {
          if (response.isError()) {
            alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
            return;
          }

          var data = response.getDataTable();
            for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
            }
          var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('columnchart'));
          chart.draw(data);
        }        
        </script>
</head>
    <body>
    <div id='columnchart'></div>
  </body>
```

If not the FROM syntax, then how would you define mutliple sheets using this method of creating a chart?

Answer (score 0):

You should set your sheet as "gid=838232320" and not in the queryString :

```js
//google.load("visualization", '1', {packages:['corechart', 'bar']});
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart'], 'callback': drawChart});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


function drawChart() {
  console.log("drawChart: Init");
 var queryString = encodeURIComponent('SELECT A, B, C, D');
 var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oKxlfCjcvjCzGh8fpTX3ax7qWbWA2uVVQgk-jzOWX3k/gviz/tq?gid=838232320&headers=1&tq=' + queryString);
  
  // Apply query language statement.
//  query.setQuery('SELECT A, B, C, D FROM "Sheet 2"');
  
  // Send the query with a callback function.
  query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
  console.log("handleQueryResponse: ", response);
  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }

  var data = response.getDataTable();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
  }
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('columnchart'));
  chart.draw(data);
}
```

```html
<div id='columnchart'></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```